# tools to generate unique & random IP addresses

Tags: networking, ip

I am in search of scripts/tools that generate random & unique IP addresses for testing purposes. I found some
1. On-line tools that generate less than 100 random IPs and
2. Scripts that generate any number of IPs but not sure if they are unique.
I am looking for a tool that can generate some 10K unique & random IP addresses.

Any idea on such techniques ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the not-guaranteed-random one to generate a million and then do something like:

```
cat results | sort -u | head -10000 > unique_results
```

Comment: was exactly looking for such technique...works great !!!
thanks a ton @RichieHindle